# Does Thorald Gray-Mane return to Whiterun after completing Stormcloak questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I completed the quest "Missing in action" after which I completed the Stormcloak questline, but I can't seem to find Thorald Gray-Mane in Whiterun. Does he return to Whiterun ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Thorald does not return to Whiterun. When you free him he makes a comment that it would be too dangerous for him and his family to be seen in public, and that he would be better off hiding from the Thalmor.

Later, you may see him in Windhelm enlisting with the Stormcloks under Galmor Stone-Fist’s command.

You can read more from Thorald’s [wiki article](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thorald_Gray-Mane)

Comment: Oh this is interesting, I just thought that after Whiterun is taken over by Stormcloaks it would be safe for him to return... thanks anyway.